# htaccess rewrite remove php extension on subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess file is under this folder:

http://localhost/project/folder/
|
|--- change this like this:
|
|_ http://localhost/project/folder/about.php
|____ http://localhost/project/folder/about
|____ http://localhost/project/folder/about/
|
|_ http://localhost/project/folder/anything.php
|____ http://localhost/project/folder/anything
|____ http://localhost/project/folder/anything/
|
|_ http://localhost/project/folder/file.php?id=8888
|____ http://localhost/project/folder/file/id/8888
|____ http://localhost/project/folder/file/id/8888/
|
|_ http://localhost/project/folder/file.php?edit=8888
|____ http://localhost/project/folder/file/edit/8888
|____ http://localhost/project/folder/file/edit/8888/

What code I found until now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule file/edit/(.*)/ file.php?edit=$1
RewriteRule file/edit/(.*) file.php?edit=$1 

RewriteRule file/id/(.*)/ file.php?id=$1
RewriteRule file/id/(.*) file.php?id=$1


# Remove file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Problem I am facing: if I try, http://localhost/project/folder/about working, but not http://localhost/project/folder/about/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^file/edit/([^/]+)/?$ file.php?edit=$1  [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^file/id/([^/]+)/?$ file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Remove file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: about.php is not opening as about or about/ :(

Comment: one other thing, http://localhost/project/folder/anything.php to http://localhost/project/folder/anything or http://localhost/project/folder/anything/ working. now, if somehow someone open, http://localhost/project/folder/anything/something it is showing, internal server error. :(